# 2 Slug in url path

Tags: django, django-views

I want the URL like this

```
example.com/lol/tournament/tournament-slug/match/match-slug
```

I did it, however, is it the right approach to use it like this? Is there a better way?   code: `leagueoflegendsgame=game[0]`

views.py

```
def lolmatch_detail(request, tournamentslug, lolslug):
    lolmatch=get_object_or_404(LeagueOfLegendsGame, lol_slug=lolslug)
    game=LeagueOfLegendsGame.objects.filter(lol_slug=lolslug)
    tournamentslug = get_object_or_404(Tournament, tournament_slug=tournamentslug, leagueoflegendsgame=game[0])
```

urls.py

```
path('lol/tournament/<str:tournamentslug>/match/<str:lolslug>', lolmatch_detail, name='lol_match_detail'),
```

models.py

```
class LeagueOfLegendsGame(Game):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    lol_slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    match=models.ManyToManyField(Match)...

class Tournament(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tournament_slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=255)
```

Comment: What about `tournament = get_object_or_404(Tournament, tourname_slug=tournament_slug, leagueoflegends__lol_slug=lolslug)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match both slug`s in a single query, like:

```
def lolmatch_detail(request, tournamentslug, lolslug):
    game = get_object_or_404(
        LeagueOfLegendsGame,
        lol_slug=lolslug,
        tournament__tournament_slug=tournamentslug
    )
    # ...
```

Here the database will make a `JOIN` to look for the `LeagueOfLegendsGame` with the `lolslug` and check if it points to a `Tournament` with the given `tournament_slug`, and return such `Tournament` if that exists.

Comment: i changed to     game = get_object_or_404(
        LeagueOfLegendsGame,
        tournament__tournament_slug=tournamentslug,
        lol_slug=lolslug
    )  ( and thanks for the answers it works)